# How to convert point coordinate when taking a snapshot?

Tags: unity, c#, textures, coordinates

Can anyone explain me please how to convert point from Screen-coordinate system to Texture 2D?
The screen size say for example 700x500 and Texture2D must be of size 1024x768. I am getting points from scene, convert them with camera.WorldToScreen and then multiply by ratio, which doesn't work correctly for some reason.
Here is my code:

```
//PROCESSING POINTS
cam_pts[i] = detector.WorldToScreenPoint(pts[i]);
cam_pts[i].y = Screen.height - cam_pts[i].y;
cam_pts[i].x = cam_pts[i].x * (ImageWidth/(float)Screen.width);
cam_pts[i].y = cam_pts[i].y * (ImageHeight/(float)Screen.height);
```

```
//SAVING CAPTURE SCREEN
RenderTexture rt = new RenderTexture(ImageWidth, ImageHeight, 24);
detector.targetTexture = rt;
Texture2D screenShot = new Texture2D(ImageWidth, ImageHeight, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
detector.Render();
RenderTexture.active = rt;
screenShot.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, ImageWidth, ImageHeight), 0, 0);
detector.targetTexture = null;
RenderTexture.active = null;
Destroy(rt);
byte[] bytes = screenShot.EncodeToPNG();
string filename = string.Format("Screenshot_{0}.png", counter);
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filename, bytes);
```

[image: Result of this conversion]
The red points must be at the corners of the pallet.
I am new in Unity and C# and will be thankful if someone explains me how to do it right.

Comment: How are you displaying this texture? Can you show us its setup in the hierarchy/scene view/inspector, or instructions to reproduce this exact case starting from a new, empty project?

Comment: I am just saving this. I need screenshots while camera is moving. So I am not displaying it. These red dots are drawn by python script. I am actually gathering data for CNN

Comment: Ah, so the border around the image and rulers along two sides that we're seeing are not part of the rendered image, but added in your Python display?

Comment: Yep. I saved a picture/screenshot and a textfile with coordinates. Python script then opens both files and draws dots. This ruler is from matplotlib

Comment: Does the problem disappear if your game screen uses the same 4:3 aspect ratio as your output buffer?

Comment: I don't know about aspect ratio... I am given screen size and output size. If output size is same as of screen, then all coordinates good

Answer (score 1):

Thanx DMGregory for taking part. I found a decision to this problem. In the saving capture screen part must be added a few rows:

```
RenderTexture rt = new RenderTexture(ImageWidth, ImageHeight, 24);
        detector.targetTexture = rt;
        Texture2D screenShot = new Texture2D(ImageWidth, ImageHeight, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);

        float aspect = detector.aspect; //preserve old aspect ratio
        detector.aspect = (float)ImageWidth / (float)ImageHeight; //set new aspect ratio according to width and height of an image 

        detector.Render();
        RenderTexture.active = rt;
        screenShot.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, ImageWidth, ImageHeight), 0, 0);
        detector.targetTexture = null;
        RenderTexture.active = null;

        detector.aspect = aspect;// return back original aspect ratio

        Destroy(rt);
        byte[] bytes = screenShot.EncodeToPNG();
        string filename = string.Format("Screenshot_{0}.png", counter);
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filename, bytes);
```

And then in the void Start()-function must be added:

```
Screen.SetResolution(ImageWidth, ImageHeight, false);
        detector = this.GetComponent<Camera>();// get camera object
        detector.aspect = (float)ImageWidth / (float)ImageHeight;// setting aspect ratio of the screen
```

This way ordinary coordinate conversion works/